# Why did this Early Version of the Watchtower Magazine include Crosses, and what do these other Symbols on the Magazine Represent?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, symbolism, sign-of-the-cross

The following is "Zion's Watch Tower and Herald of Christ's Presence, October 1, 1907."[image]

I was under the impression that symbols (especially crosses) were not allowed in the church. "Jehovah's Witnesses teach that Jesus was crucified on a stake, and that they reject the cross as a pagan symbol. No crosses are to be displayed in the worship hall, on a person, or in Jehovah's Witnesses' houses" (page 535 of AMG's Encyclopedia of World Religions, Cults, and the Occult).
Question: What do the symbols in the top corners represent, and how are these symbols associated with Watchtower?

Comment: Welcome to the Christianity SE; we are glad you are here.  Excellent first question.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for asking a great question! While you're here, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a quick overview of what this site is all about. And I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here.

Comment: I have seen those same symbols somewhere before.... hmmmm

Comment: @TheFreemason do you know of their origin and their relationship to Watchtower?

Comment: Charles Taze Russell may or may not have been a Freemason.  It's not important to us to make note of it if he were.  However it is clear that he had profound respect for that ancient institution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Jehovahs Witness teaching of the symbol of the cross was changed about the 1930's by Joseph Rutherford.
Prior to this they accepted the cross that is widely accepted in Christendom today.
So the magazine would still have a cross on it as it's publication was prior to this time

[Facts about Jehovahs Witnesses](http://www.jwfacts.com/watchtower/cross-or-stake.php)

As far as the symbolism on the magazine is concerned.  I would at a guess say that the top left hand corner is meant to represent Christ being King.  And the top right as being the guardian or defender of the Watchtower

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Thanks for taking the site tour.  When you have a chance, you may want to read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.* I look forward to reading more of your work in the future.

Answer (score -4):

The early members of the Bible Students as they were then called did many things in contrast of the Bible. The more they studied the Bible by examining the scriptures they realized they needed to change and stop what they were doing. They even celebrated Christmas, smoked, and the use of the Cross and the Crown as a symbol of faith on the early magazines. As they progressed in the truth of God's word, they openly and publicly explained why they stopped and the scriptures to support their actions. Today JW's have so much more of an understanding of the truth (the true Christians) because over 8 million witnesses are proclaiming that truth in all the inhabited earth. They are only organized religion truly obey the commandments of Jehovah and Jesus. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and in particular what constitutes a good answer.  Your answer is OK, but would be greatly improved by some references to back your claims.

Comment: "They are only organized religion truly obey the commandments of Jehovah and Jesus." - the concern being, 'as they understand them'